# Google Maps API v3 Geocoding Status is OK even if geocoded street doesn't exist

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, google-geocoder

I just discovered a strange behavior in Google Maps API V3, and more specifically with its `Geocoding` tool.
Here is an exemple : This is how I geocode my addresses :

```
var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + address + "&sensor=false");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

where `address` is a varible with a full address entered by the user.

When the address is a valid one, `response.StatusCode` is `OK`, which means, [according to the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#StatusCodes), "that no errors occurred; the address was successfully parsed and at least one geocode was returned."

But when the try to geocode this adress :

> 15 StreetWhoDoesntExist, 69009 LYON

the `StatusCode` is `OK` and the latitude / longitude returned is the center of the city (in this example, LYON, which is a real French city and its corresponding zipcode, 69009).

Is this behaviour normal ? When I entered the same address in [Google Maps](https://maps.google.fr/), it told me it can't find this address (which is the "good" behavior). So, how can I reproduce it with GMaps API in order to it refuses addesses with an unknown street name, even if the associated city and/or zipcode exists ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[API CALL](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=15%20StreetWhoDoesntExist,%2069009%20LYON&sensor=false)

Result:

```
     "partial_match" : true,
     "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ]
```

So I'd check those two or at least the `types` to determine if it found the actual street address.

Comment: Ok `types` parameter is exactly what I was looking for, I didn't see this parameter. I will do deeper tests, but it solves my problem, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is normal.  There was a result returned, just not the one you were expecting.  If you go a bit further down in the documentation you will see this:

> - geometry contains the following information:
>
>   - `location` contains the geocoded latitude, longitude value. For normal address lookups, this
>       field is typically the most important.
>   - `location_type` stores additional data about the specified location. The following values are
>       currently supported:
>
>     - `"ROOFTOP"` indicates that the returned result is a precise geocode for which we have location information accurate down to street address precision.
>     - `"RANGE_INTERPOLATED"` indicates that the returned result reflects an approximation (usually on a road)
>         interpolated between two precise points (such as intersections).
>         Interpolated results are generally returned when rooftop geocodes are
>         unavailable for a street address.
>     - `"GEOMETRIC_CENTER"` indicates that the returned result is the geometric center of a result such as a
>         polyline (for example, a street) or polygon (region).
>     - `"APPROXIMATE"` indicates that the returned result is approximate.

You will need to check the `location_type` to see how "accurate" the result returned is.  In your case the geocoder was unable to find `15 StreetWhoDoesntExist`, so the next best result was the center of the zipcode.

The `address_components[]` that are also returned with the geocode result has additional information you can use to get a better understanding of what is coming back.

The `partial_match` parameter will let you know if the geocoder did not return and exact match.  This will ususally be true with misspellings or missing address parts.

The reason maps.google.com rejects the address is because they have custom logic built into their application that is catching these types of results.  The geocoder just returns the raw result, you need to write business logic to handle those results.

Comment: I didn't see this part of the doc, sorry. I solved my problem using `types` parameter, but I will investigate with the parameters you pointing me out to improve my user experience. Thank you too !